# Calculation of Branching address on MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-architecture

I don't understand how is the branching address is calculated in in MIPS.

Here is big picture what happens to program counter(PC): `PC = PC + 4 + ((signed-extended offset)<<2)`

I see the reason why the offset number is `signed-extended` before being added to `PC`, it is just 16 bit value, that needs to be turned into 32 bit value, but why do we need to `left double shift` signed-extended number ??? 
(Also,`<<2` means that we multiply the number by 4)

While we on the subject, I will extend the question: 
When we offset from the immediate value (register), why we don't do `<<2` ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important thing to know is that the instructions are *four-byte aligned*. So, the two least significant address bits do not need to be stored, and this allows 16-bit displacement to give a 2^18-byte range.

Additionally, you may notice that displacements for data are not shifted, because data need to be byte-addressable.

Answer (score 1):

The address must be a multiple of four, so by doing the multiply by four automatically, that leaves more significant bits for actual use. (In other words, it's like you really have 18 bits in a way.)